# Платежная система на сайте

Tags: платежи

Хочу прикрутить на сайт универсальную платежную систему, чтобы можно было с различных карт или кошельков переводить на мой кошелек. Нашел одну такую, но проблема в том, что там только на webmoney можно. Так вот вопрос, есть ли такая система в которой можно организовать вывод с различных кошельков на ЯндексДеньги или Киви?

P.s. Извиняюсь, если не там задал вопрос, уже не знаю просто у кого спросить.

Comment: Таких не существует универсальных и причем чтобы на прямую на ваши кошельки переводили, вам нужны скорее всего платежные агрегаторы их много, но все они посредники и берут свою комиссию и у каждого есть свои плюсы и минусы.

Comment: @SergeyArchipov, судя по всему именно это и нужно. Я думал в сторону unitpay, но там при регистрации нужно указывать кошелек вебмани, я так понимаю на него будут начисляться все платежи от пользователей с их кошельков или банковских карт, Вот мне бы тоже самое только с возможностью выбора нужного мне кошелька (не вебмани)

Comment: так у него же есть вывод, и на киви, и на яндекс, и на пайер, может еще какие то и другие добавили, давно не пользовался